# Why is root user denied access to a file?

Tags: permissions, root, chown

I would like to understand in which cases root can be denied access to a file.
I am working on a machine I didn't configure (on my personal laptop I obivously don't have this problem) and I am having this problem which can be boiled down to simply this:

```
touch test.sh &&\
echo 'echo $PATH' >> test.sh &&\
sudo sh test.sh
```

will give the error: `sh: 0: Can't open test.sh` (`bash: test.sh: Permission denied` with `bash`).

- I tried to see if I was [under SELinux by running `getenforce`](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-check-whether-selinux-is-enabled-or-disabled/), but the command was not found.
- I tried `sudo chown root test.sh`, but it gives the error: `chown: cannot access 'test.sh': Permission denied`.
- Same thing happened when trying to change the ownership of the directory.

I am not necessarily asking for a solution to the overall problem but I want to understand how it's possible that root is denied some access.

---

EDIT

On the same machine, if I create a local user (all the above was done as a user logged in via a shared network), all works fine.

Comment: Can you try `sudo sh -c test.sh` or simply `sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'`?

Comment: Specify the path! `sudo` offers a `PATH` specifically not including `.`. `sudo sh ./test.sh`

Comment: @Rinzwind I am sure the file exists: I just created it with `touch`. I also see it with `ls`. However I do see your point from the point of view of `sudo`, when I do `sudo ls` I get `ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied`, how could this happen?. On my machine too the 3 lines do what's expected, just not on my professional computer.
RE your last point I don't get it: `sudo whoami` returns `root`.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli when doing `sudo sh -c test.sh` I get `sh: 1: test.sh: not found`. This is probably linked to what I said in [my above comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144806/why-is-root-user-denied-access-to-a-file?noredirect=1#comment1900188_1144806) where `sudo ls` gives `ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied`. Your second obviously works but I really want to be able to run a file.

Comment: @waltinator your command gives the same error. I do se that the path is different for `sudo` but I don't see how this affects anything.

Comment: as others have said always give full path to reach any executable as root or sudo ... otherwise its less secure ... also for security avoid putting '.' into PATH env var for root

Comment: @ScottStensland "otherwise its less secure " why?

Comment: Try `chmod a+x test.sh`

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi: Basically, any user which can write to a directory in root's PATH could potentially trick root into running arbitrary code. For that reason you only want directories fully under root's control to be in the root PATH, and you can't really rely on "." being fully under root's control. Specifying absolute paths to sudo is an extra protection against accidentally running a different binary as root than you thought you were.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** if you run

```
export PATH=.:$PATH # wrong
```

then your above mentioned set of commands will ~~work~~ however avoid this solution ... Why ? ... when you run an executable giving it either a full path

```
/my/cool/binary
```

or relative path

```
./../cool/binary # notice this begins with a ./  period slash
```

you directly control where the executable is coming from ... however if by mistake or by some rogue process your env var PATH gets updated with a prepend of a dir(s) which contains (wrong or malicious) executables with matching names

```
export PATH=/wrong/dir:/hackers/own/dir:$PATH
```

and you just use

```
myexecutable_name  # using naked binary name
```

you could be running

```
/wrong/dir/myexecutable_name
```

when you intended to run

```
/actual/good/dir/myexecutable_name
```

which is why production code or anything run as root should explicitly spell out where the binary is coming from

Now going back to your original question ... your code assumes PATH includes current dir '.' which it should not contain for prod ids or root

```
export PATH=.:$PATH # wrong - bad for root or prod id yet handy for dev folks
```

instead execute using full path ... problem is you want to avoid possibility of running wrong binary which happens to be in your current dir when you intended to run binary from the standard dir as defined in your PATH

Not convinced ?  spend some quality time with critical infrastructure code especially which is at an intersection between responsibilities ... where team B binary is executing a binary from team A and you will always see full path used ... another inspiration is to beef up on namespace conflicts